# Voting on closed questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

I have gotten a few up votes on a question that was voted closed.  If a question is closed, can votes on it still be taken and points given? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5):

It's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  When the question is closed, you should still be able to get and lose reputation from having people vote on it.

For more information, see [Why allow closed questions to be voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83798/333472) Adam Davis' post pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to anonymous2's answer, bear in mind that many eligible closed questions will be deleted from the site altogether by the [automatic script](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) (known as the Roomba).

> **If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.

If this happens, any rep changes from the post will be forfeited, whether this leads to a rep gain or loss. For example, if you post  a question which later gains 5 downvotes (-10 rep), you will regain +10 rep when the post is automatically deleted after closure.